# Sharepoint 2013 workflow REST: service response on filter request with httpSend activity

Tags: visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity, rest

in a declarative / visual studio workflow we want to filter a list and use a httpSend activity with

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items?$filter=Title eq 'customer'
```

for the uri request parameter. Result = no item. Putting this URL in the Browser we get the item properties as well as with

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items(1)
```

So the item is there (the httpSend Header is on "application/json; odata=verbose").

Could it be that the httpSend has got Problems with the **filter syntax and the spaces around 'eq'**?
How to examine this? How to resolve this?

Comment: Works for me, are you sure that is the internal name? The EQ operator is (by design) case sensitive.

Comment: But "AuthorId" and all the other standard fields doesn't work either. I think it's a question of wrong property syntax within the httpSend activity. Is the prefix "d." like in "d.AuthorId" the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that a request with a filter argument creates a service response of different syntax. If we use a request like

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items(1)
```

the response scheme starts with the tag "entry" whereas if we use filter like in

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items?$filter=Title eq 'customer'
```

the list items retrieved are stored in an array "results".

So the best way is partly taken from the documentation [blogs_msdn_thirusrinivasan1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thirusrinivasan1/archive/2013/10/26/sharepoint-2013-workflow-handling-dynamic-values-and-collections.aspx) concerning "Looping Thru Response Collection". We've used a GetDynamicValueProperties activity on "d.results". Then to get the list items we loop through results with a ForEach activity. That's it.

To get an idea what to look for in the service response some tools are helpful. In our case we've taken "Advanced REST client" from ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)). With this we could examine the json scheme we get.